# iphone uiimagepickerViewController choosing photolibrary video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

Am developing a application which is only selecting video form local photo library and sending it to the server. Here am fixed videoMaximumDuration as 1min..(bcoz am restricting user to choose video less than 1min).

when user choosing more than 1min video in uiimagepickerviewcontroller a text is appearing that
'Video Too Long to Send - Please select similar form video' 
Here while this text is appearing i want to disable or hide the 'Choose' button which is there in bottom of uiimagepickercontroller.

HOW to hide that choose button or disable in imagepickercontroller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this.  It is not possible to customize the picker in this way.

The best thing you can do is to warn the user before that the video must be less than 1 min. Which it sounds like you are already doing.  Then in the delegate callback

```
imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
```

Check the video is less than 1 min.  If not display an error and make the user pick again.

Or perhaps you can suggesting editing the video (which is very easy to do on iPhone).