# Is it possible to change the text 'Video Too Long to Send' in message when using 'videoMaximumDuration' in 'UIImagePickerController'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using **UIImagePickerController** to pick a video(I'm limiting the video length to 1 minute) from gallery. Here is my code:

```
- (void)chooseExistingVideo {
    CFStringRef mTypes[1] = { kUTTypeMovie };
    CFArrayRef mTypesArray = CFArrayCreate(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), (const void**)mTypes, 1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = (__bridge NSArray*)mTypesArray;
    CFRelease(mTypesArray);

    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 60.0f;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When i choose a video which is 5 minutes length the screen is coming like this:

[image]

In this screen is it possible to change the text of '**Video Too Long to Send**' message to '**Video Too Long to Add**' or is there any way to get rid of the entire message?

I need your valuable suggestions.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: got any work around for this issue?

Comment: As of I know, It's not possible. I'll let you know if it's possible in the upcoming iOS versions.

Comment: still a bug in iOS 12.4

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this answer: [iphone uiimagepickerViewController choosing photolibrary video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755371/iphone-uiimagepickerviewcontroller-choosing-photolibrary-video)

Basically there is no way to alter or change this message. I don't know when the decision to add it happened and it is completely undocumented by Apple. It only makes sense for Apple's messaging app (or any app where you send a file), and I hope they will change or remove it.

If I should come across any way to disable or change this besides what is in the above answer, I will update this post.

Answer (score -1):

Just set

```
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = false;
```

It is a way to get rid of alert view.